# How to check Exchange the Application Impersonation Permission of a meeting resource by EWS managed API?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get the calendar information of the meeting resource by an Application Impersonation account.
I need to check if the Application Impersonation account has permission to get the calendar information from the meeting resource.
(As I know the meeting resource can be set to refuse the access by the Application Impersonation account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want using EWS as the only way to check the underlying permissions would be to use the Exchange Management Shell cmdlet. However the easiest way is just process the result of EWS operation you make eg with the EWS managed API if you don't have impersonation rights then you will received an error which will indicate that you don't have Impersonation rights. eg

```
        try
        {
            //EWS request
        }catch(Exception Exception)
        {
            if(Exception is ServiceResponseException)
            {
                switch (((ServiceResponseException)Exception).ErrorCode)
                {
                    case ServiceError.ErrorImpersonateUserDenied:
                        break;
                    case ServiceError.ErrorImpersonationDenied:
                        break;
                    case ServiceError.ErrorImpersonationFailed:
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
```